# Getting error "cannot convert from 'double' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char>" when assigning a variable

Tags: c#, selenium

Hello I am new to C# and I am trying to store the value of a variable(total) into another variable(storetotal) but I am getting the following error: **cannot convert from 'double' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan'** where I have the following code

```
storetotal = int.Parse(total);
double total = 0;
```

Please help

Comment: `total` & `storetotal` are both doubles - what are you trying to do? Shouldn't `storetotal` be an `int` if you are using `int.Parse()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `total` is of type double. You can not parse doubles. You parse strings.
Why do you try to convert your double into type int and then assign it to your double `storetotal`?

Answer (score 1):

`int.Parse` only has overloads for taking either a `string` or `System.ReadOnlySpan`. It can't handle a `double` as input.

Try:

`storetotal =  Convert.ToInt32(total)`

Remember though that `int` has a smaller than the range of `double`. `Convert.ToInt32(double)` will throw an exception if it is out of range, which you might want to inside a `try/catch`.

Comment: Why would you use `Convert` when you can just cast `(int)`

Comment: An `(int)` cast just truncates e.g. 2.9 becomes 2. a `Convert` will give 3 from 2.9. Or they could do neither and control the rounding explicitly :)

Answer (score 0):

As `total` is `double`, then `int.Parse(total)` will select a nearest overload

```
public static int Parse (ReadOnlySpan<char> s, 
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer,
    IFormatProvider? provider = default);
```

(see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_Parse_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_)).

But `double` can not be implicitly casted to `ReadOnlySpan`, so you got the error menioned.

If you just need to store your `total` somewhere, you can just assign `storetotal=total` as both are of the same `double` type